# Dropzone server responded with 0 code on iOS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js, iis-8

Although there are similar questions, I have not been able to resolve the dropzone 'server responded with 0 code' on iOS.

I'm currently using Dropzone on my C# MVC web application to upload a video as well as an image, which works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox on desktop as well as Chrome on Android, but for some reason it will not upload the video on iOS or simply respond with the 0 code error but it still uploads the image none the less.

I have set the **maxAllowedContentLength** in the web.config:

```
 <security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and I have also specified the max file size in the dropzone configuration as well as include the different mimeTypes for the accepted files.

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  <remove fileExtension=".flv" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv" />
  <remove fileExtension=".m3u8" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".m3u8" mimeType="application/x-mpegURL" />
  <remove fileExtension=".ts" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".ts" mimeType="video/MP2T" />
  <remove fileExtension=".3gp" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".3gp" mimeType="video/3gpp" />
  <remove fileExtension=".mov" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mov" mimeType="video/quicktime" />
  <remove fileExtension=".avi" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".avi" mimeType="video/x-msvideo" />
  <remove fileExtension=".wmv" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".wmv" mimeType="video/x-ms-wmv" />
</staticContent>
```

Has anyone been able to resolve this issue on iOS using safari, any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Additonally I've tried to increase the connection timeout in IIS 8 and I've also added executionTimeout="180" to the web.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a two day struggle, I was finally able to solve my issue.

Rather than taking random shots in the dark and guessing a possible solution I found [this](https://medium.com/@haroonabbasi/remote-debugging-safari-iphone-ipad-ios-11-on-windows-340b403a9829) article to debug iOS on windows so I can see why the video isn't uploading or which error was returned.

I found that on iOS the file extension gets passed through has uppercase in the xhr request e.g. my-video.MP4 and in my controller the if statements where comparing the file extension as lower case as seen below:

```
if (fileExtension == ".mp4" || fileExtension == ".mov" || fileExtension == ".avi" ||  fileExtension == ".wmv" || fileExtension == ".flv" || fileExtension == ".3gp")
   {
       //saving files onto the server
   }
```

I simply converted the file extension to lower case and all seems to be working well. I hope this helps someone having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can have several reasons. How big are the files you are uploading? How long does the server execute a script? Which maximum file sizes are allowed to upload? 
I assume this will be mainly an issue of the webserver settings.

Try increase also the connection timeout in IIS: go to your website (i.e. Default Website) -> Advanced Settings -> Connection Timeout).

If this still doesn't work, see this link for some ideas: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/701

Comment: I have increased the connection timeout to the maximum value in IIS (65535 seconds) and also set the executionTimeout="180" in the web.config but still no success.